# Excel - Error formatting a column that contains dates, text and numbers

Tags: excel, format

I am currently trying to find a good format for a column that contains both dates, text and numbers. So in this column it is possible to enter in a cell "1", in the other "06/09/2018" and also in another one some text.
I also want to be able to sort my column. 
I chose the "standard" format but each time I register my file, when someone modifies it on another computer, the format change and each number appears in date format (ex: for 1, it appears as jan.-00).
Do you have any solution for that?

Thank you!!

Comment: This question seems to be off topic for Stack Overflow as it does not concern programming or scripting. You would probably be better off asking on [Superuser](https://superuser.com).

Comment: Does that format change always happen on the same computer?  What do you mean by `Standard` format?  What do you mean by `register my file`